# Numerical problem in own code to derive pdf of Tukey g

Tags: distributions, numerics

Given a $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $g>0$, the random variable

$$Y=\frac{\exp(gx)-1}{g}$$

is said to have a Tukey $g$ distribution with parameter $g$.

I wrote the following R code to get the pdf of the Tukey $g$ (I couldn t find a package that has it):

```
qgh<-function(q,g){
    (exp(g*qnorm(q))-1)/g
}
fx01<-function(z,g,p)   (qgh(q=z,g=g)-p)**2
pgh<-function(p,g) {
    optimize(fx01,interval=c(0,1),g=g,p=p)$min
}
dgh<-function(x,g,ndep=1e-5){
    (pgh(x+ndep,g=g)-pgh(x,g=g))/ndep
}
zz<-seq(-3,3,l=1000)
b1<-c(lapply(zz,dgh,g=1),recursive=TRUE)
plot(zz,b1,type='l')
```

but as a plot shows, using this naive approach, I keep getting these wired 
'hiccups' in the results. My question is: how can
 I avoid them, --eg get a smooth curve?

Comment: Are you just trying to draw a density? Since $g$ is nothing more than a shifted lognormal, why would you need code for that? Just call the present lognormal routines with a shift. Alternatively, FAdist offers a 3 parameter lognormal. If you like I can clarify what the 3 parameters are and explain how to shift the lognormal.

Comment: You might get more useful responses if you ask about what you're trying to achieve, rather than present your solution and asking where it went wrong. Alternatively, you're going to have to explain what you did with more clarity.

Comment: @Glen_b: actually, reading your first comment, the light went on in my head and I was solving my problem using the approach you suggested....I came back now to see you did it better, faster! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code (indeed I can't understand what some of the code is really trying to achieve, there).

The density you're after is a shifted lognormal.

Note that $X$ is standard normal. Hence $gX$ is $\mathcal{N}(0,g^2)$.

Hence $\exp(gX)$ is $\log\mathcal{N}(0,g^2)$.

Hence $\exp(gX)/g$ is $\log\mathcal{N}(-\log(g),g^2)$.

Hence $\exp(gX)/g-1/g$ is a $\log\mathcal{N}(-\log(g),g^2)$ shifted left by $1/g$.

You can just call the ordinary lognormal routines (`?Lognormal`) to do that.

Try running this after your code:

```
 dgh2 <- function(x,g) dlnorm(x+1/g,-log(g),g)
 lines(zz,dgh2(zz,1),col=2)
```

and see a nice smooth curve.

$\quad$ [image]